# Use hexadecimal in JUnit failure messages

Tags: junit, hex

Is there a way to configure JUnit to print integers in hexadecimal when displaying error messages?

For example, is there a way to get JUnit to display this

```
    Failure: does_not_touch_other_bits(PackedArrayTest): expected:<0xabcd1234> but was:<0>
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1
```

instead of this

```
    Failure: does_not_touch_other_bits(PackedArrayTest): expected:<-1430689110> but was:<0>
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot configure JUnit to print integers as hexadecimal values.

But you can write your own `assertEqualsHex(int expected, int value)` methods.

Another possibility is to you use this assertMethod:

```
public static void assertEquals(String message, Object expected,
            Object actual)
```

and provide the expected hex value in the message argument.

Comment: Additionally, using an Assertion framework (Hamcrest, AssertJ, Truth, etc.) and write a custom matcher for that would be an idea, but probably overkill.